# Copying until last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple sheets and I want to copy their data to another workbook on the last empty row of it. The data has a random number of rows but a defined number of columns, and I am having trouble copying it (not all the sheet, only the rows that have data) and then pasting it to the last row of the final workbook. How should I do it? I have no clue at all...

Disclaimer: I don't want to use select of activesheet as I will have multiple workbooks open and this has brought me problems. Also, the data is continues, and in this I mean that there are no empty rows in the middle of it. Also, I don't think this will change anything but this code is running inside a loop so it copies all sheets from multiple files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`col` is the column number you're trying to copy

```
For Each ws in Activeworkbook.worksheets

    lastrow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, col).end(xlup).row

    'code to copy and paste

Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume you have a handle to the worksheets, so you can use this code to copy the data:

```
Public Sub CopyAcross(oSheetFrom As Worksheet, oSheetTo As Worksheet)

    Const DATA_START_ADDRESS As String = "$A$1"

    oSheetFrom.Range(DATA_START_ADDRESS).CurrentRegion.Copy

    oSheetTo.Range("A" & oSheetTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Assuming that the data to be copied has the same start address on each sheet, which is specified as DATA_START_ADDRESS